# Which buildings were used to create Hogwarts in the Harry Potter films?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, hogwarts

It is my understanding that multiple buildings and structures around Britain were combined to create a mock up of Hogwarts, which was ultimately used as the basic working model of Hogwarts for the *Harry Potter* movies.

**Which British structures were combined to create Hogwarts?**

Comment: Why the heck was this downvoted?

Comment: I really like questions of this type: Production and behind-the-scenes movie / tv-show questions will improve the quality of the content on this site. Too often we get plot-based questions **only**, but this one is very refreshing!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the article ["Harry Potter Filming Locations in Britain"](https://www.ricksteves.com/watch-read-listen/read/articles/harry-potter-sites) on Rick Steves' site:
(for those of you that might not know, Rick Steves is an American author and television personality focusing on European travel- he had a long running travel show on PBS).

## Locations in Oxford:

> Hogwarts, Harry’s prestigious wizarding prep school, is a composite
> of several locations, many of them real places in Oxford.
>
> **Christ Church College** inspired two film sets familiar to Potter fans.
> In The Sorcerer’s Stone, the kids are ferried to Hogwarts and then
> ascend a stone staircase that leads into the Great Hall. Christ
> Church’s high-ceilinged dining hall was a model for the one seen
> throughout the films (with the weightless candles and flaming
> braziers).

Christ Church College's dining hall

[image]

Hogwarts' Dining Hall:

[image]

Christ Church College, inspiration for the Great Hall:
[image: Great Hall]
.

> Later in The Sorcerer’s Stone, Harry sneaks into the restricted book
> section of Hogwarts Library under a cloak of invisibility. This scene
> was filmed inside **Oxford’s Duke Humfrey’s Library**. Hermione reads
> about the Sorcerer’s Stone here, too.

[image]

.

> At the end of The Sorcerer’s Stone, Harry awakens in the Hogwarts
> infirmary, filmed in the big-windowed **Divinity School**, on the ground
> floor of the **Bodleian Library**; Ron also recuperates here after being
> poisoned in The Half-Blood Prince. In The Goblet of Fire (2005),
> Mad-Eye Moody turns Draco into a ferret in the New College cloister.

[image: divinity school/infirmary]
[image]
.

---

.

## Locations in Durham and Northeast England

> In The Sorcerer’s Stone, Harry walks with his white owl, Hedwig, through a snowy cloister courtyard located in **Durham’s Cathedral**.

[image: Durham]

> Harry first learns to fly a broomstick on the green grass of Hogwarts’
> school grounds, filmed inside the walls of **Alnwick Castle**, located 30
> miles from Newcastle. In The Chamber of Secrets, this is where the
> Weasleys’ flying car crashes into the Whomping Willow.

[image: Alnwick]
.

---

## Locations in Scotland

> Also in The Prisoner of Azkaban, Hogwarts Lake was filmed using **Loch Shiel, Loch Eilt,
> and Loch Morar near Fort William**, and Hagrid skips stones across the
> water at Loch Eilt. **Steal Falls, a waterfall at the base of Ben Nevis**,
> is the locale for Harry’s battle with a dragon for the Triwizard
> Tournament in The Goblet of Fire.
> .

---

.

### Locations in and around Bath

> Many scenes showing the mysterious side of Hogwarts were filmed in
> the elaborate, fan-vaulted corridors of the **Gloucester Cathedral
> cloisters**, 50 miles north of Bath. In The Sorcerer’s Stone, when Harry
> and Ron set out to save Hermione, they look down a long, dark
> Gloucester hallway and spot a 20-foot troll at the far end.

[image: hallway]

.

> In The Sorcerer’s Stone, the scene showing Harry being chosen for
> Gryffindor’s Quidditch team was shot in the halls of the 13th-century
> **Lacock Abbey**,13 miles east of Bath. Harry attends Professor Snape’s
> class in one of the Abbey’s peeling-plaster rooms — appropriate to
> Snape’s temperament. (You can visit with recommended Mad Max Tours.)

[image: Abbey]
.

> Outdoor scenes from the first Deathly Hallows, in which Harry, Ron,
> and Hermione take refuge in the woods, were filmed in the **Swinley
> Forest area of Windsor’s Great Park**.

Also, from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Places_in_Harry_Potter#Filming_locations):

> - Alnwick Castle, Northumberland (Hogwarts exterior)
> - Bodleian Library, Oxford (Hogwarts interiors)
> - Christ Church, Oxford (Hogwarts interiors)
> - Durham Cathedral (Hogwarts interiors)
> - Gloucester Cathedral (Hogwarts corridors)
> - Harrow School, (Professor Flitwick's classroom)
> - Lacock Abbey, Wiltshire (Hogwarts interiors)
> - New College, Oxford (Hogwarts cloisters)
> - St Paul's Cathedral, London (Spiral staircase in Hogwarts)

Comment: You could improve this by adding a few shots of the original buildings and interiors.

Comment: One addition -- the Hogwarts Express train is shown passing over the [Glenfinnan Viaduct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glenfinnan_Viaduct) in the western Highlands of Scotland.